# MySQL table indexing

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

I have mysql tabel called 'users'. There are two obvious fields: 'user' and 'pass'.

My authentication query is like this:

```
"SELECT pass FROM users WHERE user = ? AND pass = ?"
```

I'd tought indexing could speed up the query. Should I index only 'user' field or also 'pass' field?

Also is comparing passwords with sql query faster than with PHP string compare.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text. Store password hashes instead.

Second, index on either `user` or `pass` will help. But if you create a compound index on `(user, pass)`, it will become a covering index for this query. This means that the query can be served directly from index, without consulting data files.

Comment: Thanks, @Mchl, I missed that :-)

Comment: I am not storing passwords in plain text. That would be just silly. :)

So basicly compound index would be best thing to use?